# Opengl - Convert Texture to Array

Tags: android, opengl-es

in my android App, i have a Frame Buffer Object that takes me the rendered Scene As a texture.
the app is an Origami game and user can fold a paper freely:

[image]

[image]

in every Fold, the current rendered scene saves to a texture using fbo and then i redraw the paper with new coordinates with new texture attached to it, to seem like folded paper. and this way the user can fold the paper as many time as he wants.

I want in every frame Check the rendered scene, to determinate does the user riches to the final shape (assume that i have the final shape in a 2d-array with 0 and 1 filled, 0 for transparency and 1 for colored pixels)

what i want, is to some How, Convert this Texture to A 2d-Array filled with 0 and 1, 
0 for transparency pixel, and 1 for Colored pixel of texture.
i need this to then compare this result with a previously Known 2d-Array to determinate if the texture is the shape i want or not.

is it possible to save the texture data to an array?

i cant use glreadPixels because it is so heavy and its not possible to call it every frame.

here is the FBO class (i want to have renderTex[0] as array):

```
public class FBO {
int [] fb, renderTex;
int texW; 
int texH;    
public FBO(int width,int height){
    texW = width; 
    texH = height;
    fb = new int[1];
    renderTex= new int[1];
}
public void setup(GL10 gl){
    // generate
    ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glGenFramebuffersOES(1, fb, 0); 
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glGenTextures(1, renderTex, 0);// generate texture
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0]);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    //texBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(buf.length*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
    //gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL10.GL_MODULATE);
    gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, texW, texH, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); 
}  


public boolean RenderStart(GL10 gl){
    Log.d("TextureAndFBO", ""+renderTex[0] + " And " +fb[0]);
    // Bind the framebuffer
    ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glBindFramebufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, fb[0]);

    // specify texture as color attachment
    ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL11ExtensionPack.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0], 0);

    int error = gl.glGetError();
    if (error != GL10.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.d("err", "FIRST Background Load GLError: " + error+"      ");
    }
    int status = ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES);
    if (status != GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
    {
        Log.d("err", "SECOND Background Load GLError: " + status+"      ");;
        return true;
    }
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    return true;
} 

public void RenderEnd(GL10 gl){
    ((GL11ExtensionPack)gl).glBindFramebufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, 0);

    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    gl.glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

public int getTexture(){
    return renderTex[0];
}
public int getFBO(){
    return fb[0];
}


}
```

Comment: Why not `glReadPixels()` out of the frame buffer?

Comment: cause its too heavy, i want to keep track of texture every frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using openGL ES 3.0 and later then pbo would be a good solution. But I think you can use EGLImage. Because this only needs OpenGL ES 1.1 or 2.0.

The function to create an EGLImageKHR is:

```
EGLImageKHR eglCreateImageKHR(EGLDisplay dpy,
                          EGLContext ctx,
                          EGLenum target,
                          EGLClientBuffer buffer,
                          const EGLint *attrib_list)
```

To allocate an ANativeWindowBuffer, Android has a simple wrapper called GraphicBuffer:

```
    GraphicBuffer *window = new GraphicBuffer(width, height, PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888, GraphicBuffer::USAGE_SW_READ_OFTEN | GraphicBuffer::USAGE_HW_TEXTURE);
struct ANativeWindowBuffer *buffer = window->getNativeBuffer();
EGLImageKHR *image = eglCreateImageKHR(eglGetCurrentDisplay(), EGL_NO_CONTEXT, EGL_NATIVE_BUFFER_ANDROID, *attribs);
```

to read pixels from an FBO use one of these two methods below:

```
void EGLImageTargetTexture2DOES(enum target, eglImageOES image)

void EGLImageTargetRenderbufferStorageOES(enum target, eglImageOES image)
```

These two methods will esablish all the properties of the target GL_TEXTURE_2D or GL_RENDERBUFFER

```
uint8_t *ptr;
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image);

window->lock(GraphicBuffer::USAGE_SW_READ_OFTEN, &ptr);
memcpy(pixels, ptr, width * height * 4);
window->unlock();
```

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish what you want, you need to use a [PBO (Pixel Buffer Object)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html): You can map it to an array to read it if it were a regular array.

> OpenGL ARB_pixel_buffer_object extension is very close to
>   ARB_vertex_buffer_object. It simply expands ARB_vertex_buffer_object
>   extension in order to store not only vertex data but also pixel data
>   into the buffer objects. This buffer object storing pixel data is
>   called Pixel Buffer Object (PBO). ARB_pixel_buffer_object extension
>   borrows all VBO framework and APIs, plus, adds 2 additional "target"
>   tokens. These tokens assist the PBO memory manger (OpenGL driver) to
>   determine the best location of the buffer object; system memory,
>   shared memory or video memory. Also, the target tokens clearly specify
>   that the bound PBO will be used in one of 2 different operations;
>   GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB to transfer pixel data to a PBO, or
>   GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB to transfer pixel data from PBO.

It can be created similiar to other buffer objects:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, size, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_READ);
```

Then you can read from an FBO (or a texture) easily:

```
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
GLubyte *array = (GLubyte*)glMapBufferRange(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0, size, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);
// TODO: Do your checking of the shape inside of this 'array' pointer or copy it somewhere using memcpy()
glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

Here `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` is used as input - see the specification of [glReadBuffer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glReadBuffer.xhtml) for further details how to specify front or backbuffer to be used.

Comment: But PBO works on opengl ES 3.0 + 
i am currently using OpenglES1.0